# Common class updates controls in viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a seasoned developer in several languages, but fairly new to developing in Xcode for IOS.

I have an issue I have been trying to resolve for a couple of weeks now.  I have tried several concepts from this site and others, to no avail.

Rather than posting all the examples of everything I have tried, let me give you the overview of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Can anyone offer some hints of keywords to search for, or any link to something similar to what I'm looking for?

I have a few view controllers and one common class for processing.  In the common class there is a timer that, when fires, calls some code in that same class.  From there, I need to be able to both get and set properties of controls in the view controllers.

The closest example I found relies on code from the view controller calling the common class (so we have a handle) and allows me to update a label control text.  However this is not what I'm looking for, as I need to get and set properties of several view controllers without necessarily having that view controller call the common class.

I've tried delegates, protocols, and others, but all examples I've tried fall short on this point.

Thanks very much in advance!

[EDITED TO ADD AN EXAMPLE OF LATEST ATTEMPT]
I have instantiated a common class as common in vcHome.m and then call a method in the common class

vcHome.h:

```
@interface vcHome : UIViewCOntroller
{
  // Make this control available to other classes
  UILabel *label1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
```

vcHome.m:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{  
  ...
  //Pass vcHome to clsCommon
  [common saveVCHome:self];
}
```

Then in clsCommon.h:

```
// Declare out shared instance global var storage
+(clsCommon *) sharedInstance; 

// Property to store a pointer to vcHome via global var storage
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *vcHome;

-(void)saveVCHome:(UIViewController *)vcHome;
```

And clsCommon.m:

```
#import <vcHome.h>
...

// The global var storage
+(clsCommon) sharedInstance
{
  static clsCommon *myInstance = nil;
  if(myInstance == nil) {myInstance = [[self class] alloc] init];}
}

-(void)saveVCHome:(vcHome *)vcHomePassed
{
  [clsCommon sharedInstance].vcHome = &vcHomePassed;
}
```

From then on I have a pointer saved to the vcHome view controller for future use.

What I'm hoping to get to is to be able to reference the original instance of the vcHome view controller that was instanciated by a tab bar.  When a timer fire in clsCommon (all my itself - not by anything passed from vcHome) and be able to set/get properties of a control in the vcHome view controller, as such:

clsCommon.m:

```
-(void)timerFire
{
  [clsCommon sharedInstance].vcHome.label1.text = @"updated from clsCommon";
}
```

Two questions on this.
1. I'm getting an error message about indirect pointer versus objective-c pointer, so my syntax is off.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
2. Is this even possible?

I've tried approaches where I re-instantiate the vcHome view controller, but that would be a new instance and of course would not allow me to set a control property that would show up in the originally instantiated view controller, hence by attempt here to save a pointer to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks Michael, for suggesting delegates.  The do work, but not for this case because (unless I'm wrong) a class (my view controllers) can be multiple delegates, but a class (my common class) cannot be delegated out to multiple view controllers.

I ended up achieving this very simply through NSNotifications.  Rather than trying to make the common class directly get/set the controls in the view controllers, the common class sets properties in a shared instance singleton (for all view controllers/classes to use) and then as needed, sends out notifications to the appropriate view controllers.

Notice this is not only very simple to set up, but also handles multiple post-listen pairs.

clsCommon.m:

```
- (void)processSomething {
  // Some processing changes information that is ultimatley displayed on the Info screen.  Tell the Info screen to update.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"updateInfoScreen" object:nil];
  // Some processing changes information that is ultimatley displayed on the History screen.  Tell the History screen to update.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"updateInfoScreen" object:nil];
}
```

And listen for those notifications in the view controller classes

vcInfo.m:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
 //Listen for notifications
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateInfo) name:@"updateInfoScreen" object:nil];
}

- (void) dealoc {
  //This method handles stopping the listener when the app is shut down (or this view controller is dismissed)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"updateInfoScreen" object:nil];
}

- (void) updateInfo {
  //Put code here that does whatever you want to update this screen
}
```

vcHistory.m:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
 //Listen for notifications
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateHistory) name:@"updateHistoryScreen" object:nil];
}

- (void) dealoc {
  //This method handles stopping the listener when the app is shut down (or this view controller is dismissed)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"updateHistoryScreen" object:nil];
}

- (void) updateHistory {
  //Put code here that does whatever you want to update this screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your common class to get a "do something" message out to all view controllers, you have a couple choices that I can think of off the top of my head:

1)

You could create a subclass of UIViewController (e.g. "`JohnViewController`") and then base all your subsequent view controllers off of that, meaning they can all inherit the same properties (and setters and getters).

2)

You could have your view controller subclasses register to observe a [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/index.html) your common class sends out when it's time to set and/or get.

Comment: Hey Michael, Thanks for answering.  I like your first suggestion.  The problem I've had in trying that is that when I instantiate the view controllers from the common class, that is a new instance.  Do you know of a way to reference the original instance of the view controllers?

Comment: Each view controller has to be a new instance and a new object.  If you want to keep some kind of handle or pointer to the original instance, you could pass it along in the NSNotification as the [`object`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNotification/object) that sent the notification.

Comment: And I have been able to do that in tests.  However, my problem is that (and maybe I should have said this in the beginning) I am using the storyboard and a tab controller.  So all the viewcontrollers are instantiated outside of my control - no opportunity to pass anything along.  Maybe the question is how to get a pointer to an already instantiated viewcontroller without receiving a call from it?